# How to find each pixel between two points in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel

Hello sir/mem i m making Desktop App in java Swing for doctor.I want to find each pixel value not count between two points.suppose i have one point (100,145) and second point is (173,190) and i want to get pixel between this two points.means every pixels of (x,y) value between that two points.so how can i do that?

Comment: so you want a rectangle with opposing corners P1(x1,y1) and P2(x2,y2)? Or all the pixels on the connecting line between P1 and P2?

Comment: no i have irregular shape means random shape.

Comment: If what you want isn't any of the two things I mentioned in my previous comment, can you illustrate it a bit more?

Comment: sorry .i want to get all pixel on connecting line between P1 and P2.

Comment: then TomA's answer should do the trick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look up the [Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). [Here](http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/drawing-line-using-bresenham-algorithm/) is an implementation in Java.

Comment: But, Is there any class in java to get all pixels lie on line between two points?

Comment: He just gave you an implementation on how to draw the line. Exchange the code that draws the line with code that simply stores the point in a list and then return that.